Nginx config to display files using file server
Nginx config to display files using file server
I want to display two mount points using nginx and they should be password protected.
What will be the config.
/data and /reserv - i need to display on file server.

While the question could be solved by research, it also has been with nginx directory listing on Ubuntu
here is a shortcut for this offtopic questionb
location /data 
root /data
    autoindex on;
}


location /reserv 
root /reserv
    autoindex on;
}

remind that you need to adjust the access rights.

server {
listen 80;
server_name fin-server;
root /test;
autoindex on;
auth_basic "Restricted Access";
auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.global;
location /test {
    alias /test/share;
    autoindex on;
    index index.html;
    auth_basic "Restricted Access";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/conf.d/.htpasswd-test;
}

}
its never asking  for password, what could be the issue here

please open a different question, since the original one is solved imho.
